# Should I put variables inside an if conditional?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I want to know, according to good practices, what is the most convenient way to put variables in this case:

If you have a function, where its content is going to be executed only if the conditional statement is true, where would you put the variables?

```
  addMessage (text) {
    let lastMessage = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.messages);
    if (text.length) {
      ChatActions.addMessage(text);
      lastMessage.scrollTop = lastMessage.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
```

Or like this:

```
  addMessage (text) {
    if (text.length) {
      let lastMessage = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.messages);
      ChatActions.addMessage(text);
      lastMessage.scrollTop = lastMessage.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think tricks are OK as long as they aren't bugs. If they speed things up, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, Definitely

As stated in many JavaScript style guides:

---

#### [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide() {](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#13.4)

> 13.4 Assign variables where you need them, but place them in a reasonable place.
>
> > Why? let and const are block scoped and not function scoped.

---

#### [Principles of Writing Consistent, Idiomatic JavaScript](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js)

```
// 2.B.1.4
// const and let, from ECMAScript 6, should likewise be at the top of their scope (block).

// Bad
function foo() {
  let foo,
    bar;
  if ( condition ) {
    bar = "";
    // statements
  }
}
// Good
function foo() {
  let foo;
  if ( condition ) {
    let bar = "";
    // statements
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the if statement. The lastMessage function is required by the IF statement only, according to your code - so you should enclose it. Otherwise you are performing a computation every time you run your if check, regardless of whether or not you are going to need it. That would be wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `if` statement if it is not used outside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put it within the if statement. Especially if the variable assignment is costly as it is never being used unless the if statement is satisfied.